# Select row dependent on other rows in the table

Tags: mysql

Apologies if this has been asked before but I really didn't know what to search and thus not sure how to word the question title so fingers crossed.

I'm building quite a common system where one product can have multiple categories and on the front-end, the user can search for products specifying multiple categories.

Say we had the following schema and data ( I cant post images yet, apologies, please see link )-

**table name: product_categories**

Data:

[image]

*The products table is very standard - id, name, amount etc.*

So product 1 has 2 categories.

If the user checks 2 tickboxes on the search page which represent category 2 and 3, how would I query that so only products which have both of those categories come back?

Something such as follows doesn't work, as there is no one row in that which has a category id of 2 AND a category id of 3:

```
SELECT * from product_categories where `category_id` = 2 AND `category_id` = 3;
```

I've tried using WHERE IN aswell, however, this would return product 1 even if i was looking for products which had both category id 2 and 6 ( for example ) which I don't want.

This is part of a bigger query however, I will be able to apply the solution if I manage to find one.

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestions guys, much appreciated. I think found a solution, this seems to produce the expected results but I'll be writing some more Unit Tests around my method to ensure it works.

The solution I found is as follows:

    select * from products_categories where category_id in (2,3) HAVING count(distinct(id)) = 2

So this uses WHERE IN, however, using HAVING, it then checks the count of unique records returned and ensures it's equal to the amount of categories provided.

Cheers,
Darren

*PS: Not sure how to specify MySQL syntax highlighting, apologies*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks for the suggestions guys, much appreciated. I think found a solution, this seems to produce the expected results but I'll be writing some more Unit Tests around my method to ensure it works.

The solution I found is as follows:

```
select * from products_categories where category_id in (2,3) HAVING count(distinct(id)) = 2
```

So this uses WHERE IN, however, using HAVING, it then checks the count of unique records returned and ensures it's equal to the amount of categories provided.

Cheers, 
Darren

Answer (score 0):

Something along this way should work

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM product_categories 
            WHERE product_id = products.id AND category_id = 2) 
    AND 
    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM product_categories 
            WHERE product_id = products.id AND category_id = 3)
    ...
```

Other solution is to generate JOIN for each category.

```
SELECT * FROM products
JOIN product_categories AS cs1 ON cs1.product_id = products.id 
                               AND cs1.category_id = 2
JOIN product_categories AS cs2 ON cs2.product_id = products.id 
                               AND cs2.category_id = 3
...
```

Unless you expect product_categories to be bigger than tens of millions of rows, both solutions should work reasonably, if correct indexes are created.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a sub-query here:

```
SELECT * from product_categories where id IN (SELECT id from product_categories where `category_id` = 2) AND IN (SELECT id from product_categories where `category_id` = 3)
```

I am not 100% sure this works (long time since I worked with SQL)